# Simple calculations on specific rows in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have the following data:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

boxes = {'Students': ['Alice','Alice','Alice','Bob','Bob','Red','Red','Red','Red'],
         'Subjects': ['Math','History','Economics','Economics','Math','Sociology','Ethics','History','Economics'],
         'Grade': [100,75,85,95,100,85,75,78,82]
        }

df = DataFrame(boxes, columns= ['Students','Subjects','Grade'])
```

I want to find the average grade and the number of classes that each of `Alice` and `Red` took:

So the output I want is

```
          GPA      Count
Students        
Alice     86.67    3
Red       80.00    4
```

Are there any built-in pandas functions that do these? I realize that the following code

```
g = df.groupby('Students')['Grade']
df1 = pd.concat([g.mean().round(2), g.count()], axis=1)
df1.columns = ['GPA', 'Count']
```

will find what I want for all students, but I want to be able to find these for specific students.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`named aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) here.

```
df.groupby('Students').agg(GPA = ('Grade','mean'),
                           Count = ('Grade','count'))

                GPA  Count
Students
Alice     86.666667      3
Bob       97.500000      2
Red       80.000000      4
```

To get only values of `Alice` and `Red` create a mask using [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then `groupby`

```
mask = df.Students.str.contains(r'\bAlice\b|\bRed\b') 
#or
# mask = (df.Students =='Alice') | (df.Students=='Red')

df[mask].groupby('Students').agg(GPA = ('Grade','mean'),
                           Count = ('Grade','count'))

                GPA  Count
Students
Alice     86.666667      3
Red       80.000000      4
```

Or like @jezrael suggested you can use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) here.

```
mask = df.Students.isin(['Alice', 'Red'])
df[mask].groupby('Students').agg(GPA = ('Grade','mean'),
                           Count = ('Grade','count'))
```

- Timeit results for creating boolean mask

  - `isin` 111 µs ± 6.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
  - `.str.contains` 146 µs ± 3.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

    - Details about the regex used [here in `regex101`.](https://regex101.com/r/9wxNVK/1)
  - `boolean mask chaining` 261 µs ± 8.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)